# System of three coupled LDEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have three equations, with X, Y and Z being time-dependent and all others being constant parameters:

X’ = aX + bY + m ;
Y’ = cX + dY ;
Z’ = eX + fY + n

I arrived at the above set of equations after reducing Z as a function of X and Y. (Z = constant - X - Y)

How do I arrive at the solution for this system?

Comment: One approach is to solve the system

$$ \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\dot x} \\ 
  {\dot y} 
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  a&b \\ 
  c&d 
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  x \\ 
  y 
\end{array}} \right] + \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  m \\ 
  0 
\end{array}} \right] $$

with the [variation of constants formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Variation_of_constants) and then explicitly integrate the third equation once you have solutions of $x$ and $y$.